# VBA RegEx scraping bounced emails in MS Outlook

Tags: regex, vba, email-bounces

I'm trying to expand the functionality of some Outlook email scrapping VBA code. I get bounce-back emails on a regular basis and would like to keep track of these (for deletion) by exporting said email address to MS Excel.

The code works, to a point. I can only scrape the first email address within a typical bounce-back notification email using RegEx. The mail servers for the company that I work for aggregate emails from the same domain into one notification email. Consequently, I get multiple notification emails that contain multiple bounced emails.

How do I get RegEx to cycle through the entire notification email to gather all email addresses??? I'm a little stuck right now because — admittedly — I don't know much about RegEx and "adopted" the majority of this code...

Thank you for your help Stackoverflow!!!

```
Sub Extract_Invalid_To_Excel()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim obj As Object
Dim stremBody As String
Dim stremSubject As String
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim xlwkbk As Object 'Excel.Workbook
Dim xlwksht As Object 'Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRng As Object 'Excel.Range

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olExp = olApp.ActiveExplorer

Set olFolder = olExp.CurrentFolder

'Open Excel
Set xlApp = GetExcelApp
xlApp.Visible = True
If xlApp Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitProc

Set xlwkbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlwksht = xlwkbk.Sheets(1)
Set xlRng = xlwksht.Range("A1")
xlRng.Value = "Bounced email addresses"

'Set count of email objects
count = olFolder.Items.count

'counter for excel sheet
i = 0
'counter for emails
x = 1

For Each obj In olFolder.Items '**Loops through selected Outlook folder**
    xlApp.StatusBar = x & " of " & count & " emails completed"
    stremBody = obj.Body
    stremSubject = obj.Subject

    If checkEmail(stremBody) = True Then '**Checks email for keywords in email
        'MsgBox ("finding email: " & stremBody)

        '**RegEx to find email addresses within message body
        With RegEx
            .Pattern = "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .Global = False
            Set olMatches = .Execute(stremBody) 'Executes RegEx function

            'Loop through RegEx matches
            For Each match In olMatches
                xlwksht.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = match
                i = i + 1
            Next match
        End With
        'TODO: move or mark the email that had the address extracted
    Else
        '**To view the items that aren't being parsed uncomment the following line
        'MsgBox (stremBody)
    End If

    x = x + 1
Next obj
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("Invalid Email addresses are done being extracted")

ExitProc:
Set xlRng = Nothing
Set xlwksht = Nothing
Set xlwkbk = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set emItm = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetExcelApp() As Object
' always create new instance
On Error Resume Next
Set GetExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function checkEmail(ByVal Body As String) As Boolean
    Dim keywords(3) As String
    keywords(0) = "recipient's e-mail address was not found"
    keywords(1) = "error occurred while trying to deliver this message"
    keywords(2) = "message wasn't delivered"

    'Default value
    checkEmail = False
     For Each word In keywords
        If InStr(1, Body, word, vbTextCompare) > 1 Then
            checkEmail = True
            Exit For
        End If
     Next word
End Function
```

To provide more detail. I would receive hundreds of emails which contain the following text:

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:

John.Doe@abc.com
The recipient's e-mail address was not found in the recipient's e-mail system. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please check the e-mail address and try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.

Morgan.Freedman@abc.com
The recipient's e-mail address was not found in the recipient's e-mail system. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please check the e-mail address and try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.

Michael.Jordan@abc.com
The recipient's e-mail address was not found in the recipient's e-mail system. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please check the e-mail address and try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.
```

The code above is able to grab the first email address in the email body text (i.e. John.Doe@abc.com), but doesn't see the other two email addresses...

The rest of the code works flawlessly. It exports the email addresses that it does find into Excel.

Comment: what do you mean by "entire notification email " ?? How are you running this code??

Comment: 1) I'm running the code directly in MS Outlook. The code then opens an Excel file in imports the RegEx matches.
2) "entire notification email" refers to the fact that there are multiple bounced emails within one notification email. The mail servers for the company that I work for aggregate emails from the same domain into one notification email. Consequently, I get multiple notification emails that contain multiple bounced emails. to expand on this... all emails originating from (for example) yahoo are grouped into one notification email (i.e. in a list within one email).

Comment: Can you run the code agist the folder using "Run rules now".

Comment: This is not a simple Outlook "rules" setup... I'm not sure what you're referring to. This is a VBA program that utilizes RegEx.

Comment: you can add the VBA code or function to the outlook and can run with the "Set up rules" or  "Run rules now".

Comment: This doesn't address the problem. Please help with the RegEx loop. I can run the VBA code no problem in Outlook.

Comment: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62

Comment: Please saw your input email and your expected outout in your question.

Comment: Again, there are multiple emails WITHIN one notification email. And there are multiple notification emails. Full code and more detail provided in above original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While being still new to the RegEx function, I blindly altered the code slightly.

I changed the RegEx.Global boolean to True and this code will work flawlessly.

```
With RegEx
   yadda yadda yadda
   .Global = True
End With
```

Well - thanks in any case. Hope this helps other people!!!

Comment: The code above started to fail by producing all the text as a combination of questionmarks ("?") and fours ("4") for some reason. I found out that there's an issue with how Outlook reads message/report bodies.
 
To fix this, you need to convert the text into unicode text...

[code]    stremBody = obj.body
    stremSubject = obj.Subject
    
    ' Converts text into Unicode (readable) code
    stremBody = StrConv(stremBody, vbUnicode)[code}

Answer (score 1):

I'm receiving up to 200 bounced email notices which each large email distribution. With Constant Contact it’s easy, because the tool processes all of the bounced addresses and codes into a nice file.  With Outlook, I’m on my own, but I prefer it for other reasons.
So I came up with a procedure and VBA macro to accomplish the task.  First I place all of the emails I wish to process into one folder and have it selected.  Using Outlook 2010, I go to FILE -> OPTIONS -> ADVANCED -> EXPORT.  From there I choose [EXPORT TO A FILE](http://www.cumc.columbia.edu/it/howto/email/exp.html) (Next) and then the last option, TAB SEPARATED VALUES (Windows).  You then select the name and folder location to store the one single TXT file that has combined all of the emails in the folder.
Open the file into Msft Word and run the following VBA macro:

```
Sub Bounced_Email_Harvester()
'
' Bounced-Email Text-Process Macro
'
Dim flag As Boolean
' DocLen is to maintain Document length in characters
Dim DocLen As Long
' Try to speed up Word by suspending unnecessary tasks
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Draft = True
Options.Pagination = False
Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = False
Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Remove extraneous bracket characters < & >
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ">>>"
        .Replacement.Text = "###"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "<<<"
        .Replacement.Text = "VVV"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.WholeStory
DocLen = Len(Selection)
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
' CORE OF MACRO IS WITHIN THIS LOOP
Do While DocLen > 800
    ' Selects text until next @ sign is reached - locating email addresses
    flag = True
    While flag = True
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        DocLen = DocLen - 1
        If Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = "@" Or DocLen < 2 Then flag = False
        Wend
    flag = True
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    DocLen = DocLen + 1
    While flag = True
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        DocLen = DocLen + 1
    'Locate the Beginning of email seeking demarkations (brackets, space, tab, paragraph)
        If Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = "<" Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = "[" Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = "(" Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = " " _
        Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = Chr$(9) Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = Chr$(13) Or DocLen < 2 Then flag = False
    Wend
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    flag = True
    While flag = True
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        DocLen = DocLen - 1
'Locate the End of email seeking demarkations (brackets, space, tab, paragraph)
        If Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = ">" Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = "]" Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = ")" Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = " " _
        Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = Chr$(9) Or Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = Chr$(13) Or DocLen < 2 Then flag = False
    Wend
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.Previous(Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1).Select
    DocLen = DocLen + 1
    Selection.TypeParagraph
Loop
' END OF CORE MACRO LOOP
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.Previous(Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1).Select
    Selection.TypeParagraph
' Major work done - now some pesky house cleaning....
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "mailto:"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ":550^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "<^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = ";^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "...^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ".^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
MsgBox ("Count: " & DocLen)
End Sub
```

Word will churn away for perhaps 10 or 15 minutes and may seem to be locked up.  I click away to another app and sometimes watch Task Manager to confirm its still working based upon the performance monitor.  In the morning I'll go make coffee after starting it.  It will eventually finish with a msg box providing a meaningless number.  Click it to go away.  It’s now done and you will have a long column of paragraph-separated email addresses.  It seems to reliably extract 100% of the emails and more; for example some mail server respond with derivations of the email domain such as @us.att.com and @att.com or @jpmogan.com and @jpchase.com for the same user.

Copy the whole thing and drop into an Excel column.  From here sort the list and delete the obvious chaff, the whole top 20% that are email addresses starting with numbers, the email addresses that start with envelope, header, mailer, postmaster, SMTP, X-Sender and the large repetition of your sending email address.  Then run a pivot table upon it to eliminate all of the duplicates.  You now have your email list to import into your dB to mark as bounced email addresses.  The whole post-processing after the Word macro finishes only takes me 10 to 15 minutes.  I probably spend more time than needed, because invalid email addresses will simply be ignored by my dB linkage.

The macro does not extract bounce codes, so you don’t know it it’s soft bounce (mailbox full) or a hard bounce (Recipient not Found).  You could try to discern these before you drop them in the folder or you could adopt a policy to require two bounces over time before a permanent delete.  Your call.

I should note that I’m NOT a VBA programmer.  I learned the Basic language 40 years ago on a Commodore Computer and sometimes dabble with a few function for Msft Access.  Most of my experience with VBA for Word is limited to recording macros and then using the auto-generated code to automate a few repetitive tasks.  Someone that knows what they are doing can likely vastly improve on my code, but it works for me has has been a big time saver.

Answer (score 0):

After much hunting I was able to come up with the following function.  Some of the body text still contains invalid characters (no idea why) but overall it is about 90% correct.  This function parses a passed Outlook Items collection and adds all unique email addresses (found in the body of a ReportItem) to a String List, which is written to the Immediate window at the end.

```
Private Sub ListEmailAddresses(outlookItems As Outlook.Items)
  Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Nothing
  Try
    Dim emailAddresses As New List(Of String)
    If TypeOf outlookItems.Parent Is Outlook.MAPIFolder Then
      folder = CType(outlookItems.Parent, Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    End If
    For i = 1 To outlookItems.Count
      Dim objItem As Object = outlookItems(i)
      Try
        If TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.ReportItem Then
          Dim rpt As Outlook.ReportItem = TryCast(objItem, Outlook.ReportItem)
          Dim temp() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(rpt.Body.ToArray())
          Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
          For z As Integer = 0 To temp.Length - 1
            sb.Append(Chr(temp(z)))
          Next
          Dim rptBody As String = sb.ToString
          Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(rptBody, _
                     "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})")
          Dim results(mc.Count - 1) As String
          For x As Integer = 0 To results.Length - 1
            Dim emailAddr As String = ValueIfNull(mc(x).Value, "").ToLower
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailAddr) Then
              If Not emailAddresses.Contains(emailAddr) Then
                emailAddresses.Add(emailAddr)
              End If
            End If
          Next
        End If
      Catch ex As Exception
        ' Do Something if you care.
      Finally
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objItem)
      End Try
    Next
    emailAddresses.Sort()
    Debug.WriteLine(emailAddresses.ToSeparatedString(Environment.NewLine))
  Catch ex As Exception
    ' Do Something if you care.
  Finally
    If folder IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder)
  End Try
End Sub
```